# Weird CPU usage in OpenGL program

Tags: c++, opengl, mfc, cpu-usage

In an MFC-program I built myself I have some weird problems with the CPU usage.

I load a point cloud of around 360k points and everything works fine (I use VBO buffers which is the way to do it from what I understand?). I can move it around as I please and notice no adverse effects (CPU usage is very low, GPU does all the work). But then at certain angles and zoom values I see the CPU spike on one of my processors! I can then change the angle or zoom a little and it will go down to around 0 again. This is more likely to happen in a large window than a small one.

I measure the FPS of the program and it's constantly at 65, but when the CPU spike hits it typically goes down around 10 units to 55. I also measure the time SwapBuffers take and during normal operation it's around 0-1 ms. Once the CPU spike hits it goes up to around 20 ms, so it's clear something suddenly gets very hard to calculate in that function (for the GPU I guess?). This something is not in the DrawScene function (which is the function one would expect to eat CPU in a poor implementation), so I'm at a bit of a loss.

I know it's not due to the number of points visible because this can just as easily happen on just a sub-section of the data as on the whole cloud. I've tried to move it around and see if it's related to the depth buffer, clipping or similar but it seems entirely random what angles create the problem. It does seem somewhat repeatable though; moving the model to a position that was laggy once will be laggy when moved there again.

I'm very new at OpenGL so it's not impossible I've made some totally obvious error.

This is what the render loop looks like (it's run in an MFC app via a timer event with 1 ms period):

```
    // Clear color and depth buffer bits
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Draw OpenGL scene
    OGLDrawScene();

    unsigned int time1 = timeGetTime();

    // Swap buffers
    SwapBuffers(hdc);

    // Calculate execution time for SwapBuffers
    m_time = timeGetTime() - time1;

    // Calculate FPS
    ++m_cnt;
    if (timeGetTime() - m_lastTime > 1000)
    {
        m_fps = m_cnt;
        m_cnt = 0;
        m_lastTime = timeGetTime();
    }
```

Comment: I can't see much in of the actual code in your question. Can you please provide litte bit more? And just for clarification: do you call DrawScene and SwapBuffers one thousand times per second? This is a huge number.

Comment: If you refer to the 1000 value it's just determining when 1 second has passed (1000 ms) and update the fps value. It loops around 65 times per second but that's not possible for me to modify as it's up to opengl.   As to code, I don't really know what to show, it's a lot of code...

Comment: I was referring to your statement "it's run in an MFC app via a timer event with 1 ms period". Therefore I wanted to ask if this is really called that often and what the resolution of your timer is.

Comment: Right, I understand you now. I do indeed run it on a timer with 1 ms period, but even so the loop is only run 65 times per second... that is a bit weird come to think of it, especially given that the execution time of the entire loop is around 0-1 ms in normal cases :-/

Comment: The idea is to strip down the code to as much as possible to identify the problem. If you remove parts and the issue ceases to exist this is (in most cases) a clear hint where the problem lies. On the other hand if you are left with only a few lines of code and the problem is still there the analysis is much simpler (for us but also for you).

Comment: To begin with I want to figure out how a function that should be run 1000 times a second ends up running only 65 times per second... what sort of magic is this? To be honest I copied most of this code from a tutorial, but looking closer at it I can not find any indication to how this can happen.

Comment: Ok I put bad timer resolution as the reason for the 65 fps. I could just as well have given 15 as the period. I tried removing all rendering except the points but that didn't make any difference. I also loaded a small subset of points (10k) and then the error never appears. For some reason the GPU load goes up extremely when using a lot of points in certain angles but not in other angles which I think is very weird. Can it be a driver bug?

Comment: If you get the current GL error value, do you see errors correlated with the slowdown?

Comment: Does is slow down reliably for a certain camera position?  Or randomly?

Comment: @Autopulated: Good idea, I didn't know that functionality existed... I'll check that out when I get back to work tomorrow. @genpfault: It reliably slows down for certain camera positions; you can move away from the position so it speeds up again, and then back and it will slow down a second time. I have not found any reliable way of reproducing it though, I have no idea what so ever what actually makes it happen to begin with.

Comment: Not related to your slowdown, but if you experience framerates of around 60fps, when you expect something much faster, then that might be due to the vsync. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_tearing#V-sync

Comment: I actually measured the time from the render function ending to the next time it started to around 15 ms, so windows really doesn't run it more often than 65 times/second. If there was a V-sync I would expect SwapBuffers to block all the time instead of just sometimes, and the CPU would always be maxed out. It's quite possible a WM_TIMER message can't be sent faster than every 15 ms.

Comment: WM_TIMER resolution usually defaults to 10ms.  Call timeBeginPeriod(1) to set the maximum scheduler resolution (1ms).  Also SwapBuffers won't necessarily block every time if Vsync is enabled if you are already throttling the rate of your render loop.  The GPU buffers frames ahead of you, so SwapBuffers will only block if that queue is full.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I think I have figured out how this can happen.

To begin with the WM_TIMER messages doesn't seem to be generated more often than every 15 ms at best, even when using timeBeginPeriod(1), at least on my computer. This resulted in the standard 65 fps I was seeing.

As soon as the scene took more than 15 ms to render, SwapBuffers would be the limiting factor instead. SwapBuffers seem to busy-wait, which resulted in 100% CPU usage on one core when this happened. This is not something that occurred at certain camera angles, but is a result of a fluidly changing fps depending on how many points were shown on the screen at the time. It just appeared to spike whenever rendering happened to hit a time over 15 ms and started to wait at SwapBuffers instead.

On a similar note, does anyone know of a function like "glReadyToSwap" or something like that? A function that indicates if the buffers are ready to be swapped? That way I could choose another method for rendering with a higher resolution (1 ms for example) and then each ms check if the buffers are ready to swap, if they aren't just wait another ms, so as to not busy-wait.

Comment: No, SwapBuffers is not busy waiting, Windows just shows you a wrong number there. Add a Sleep(0); after SwapBuffers the reported CPU usage should go way down.

Comment: WM_TIMER is not a good idea if you're after drawing animations. Instead just call the render function in a loop as fast as possible and measure the time it took to process a full frame. Use High Resolution Timers for that!. SwapBuffers is not (just) waiting for the rendering to finish, it's more likely waiting for the graphics card performing a Vertical Sync. If you disable V-Sync (in the driver settings) SwapBuffers will not wait and you can observe tearing artifacts.

Comment: @datenwolf: no it really does block, adding any Sleep functions makes no difference. I can safely say that the CPU gets stuck on SwapBuffers until the card is ready to actually swap the buffers. And yes WM_TIMER is not a good idea, however I still want an alternative to the busy-waiting of SwapBuffers. I know it's not due to V-Sync because then it should also hit at 65 fps if my screen is 60Hz. Instead it hits whenever the card takes longer to render than the loop period of WM_TIMER.

Comment: Yes of course SwapBuffers blocks, that's the whole idea of it. Create a second thread for doing stuff outside the rendering thread. Once SwapBuffers blocks the other thread will get all CPU time. If Sleep(0) doesn't reduce the reported CPU time use Sleep(1). Anyway, don't try to implement some ridiculous timing scheme. Just create an additional thread. Also the CPU is not stuck on SwapBuffers, it's just the thread that called SwapBuffers that blocks until it's return.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that (at least a while back), ATI drivers tend to like to spin-wait a little too aggressively, while NVidia drivers tend to be interrupt driven. Technically spin-waiting is faster, assuming you have nothing better to do. Unfortunately, today you probably do have something better to do on another thread.

I think the OP's display drivers may indeed be spin-waiting.